# how to get value from php select item with java script, or jquery, where select item value is from query mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

i have autocomplete function in jquery like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    `...`
$("#tag").autocomplete("autocomplete.php?bro="+valBro, {
        selectFirst: true
    });`
```

i need to get value from selected item from my php code for my valBro variabel, my php code like this:

```
<select name="region_name" id="region_name"> 
<?php
$regionQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM region ORDER BY id_region");
while($reg=mysql_fetch_array($regionQuery)){
echo "<option value=\"$reg[id_region]\">$reg[region_name]</option>\n";
          }
 ?>
    </select>
```

I have try to add jquery code in my above function

```
 var valBro=$("#region_name").val();
```

but give me nothing
I have also try to add

```
var valBro=document.getElementById("region_name").value;
```

I have try to set valBro variabel as global variabel, and call change.function like this before function autocomplete

```
$("#region_name").change(function(){
valBro = $("#region_name").val();
```

});
And got nothing...
Any help?

Comment: Do you get any console errors?

Comment: no there is no error,  is it possible to get the value from html objeck where the value from query?

Answer (score 2):

Your data shouldn't be show because you are not providing any query  in this line

```
$reg=mysql_fetch_array($region)
```

but your query is in this variable

```
$regionQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM region ORDER BY id_region");
```

Try like this

```
$reg=mysql_fetch_array($regionQuery)
```

**EDIT**

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var tag = $("#tag"),   
    region_name = $("#region_name"),
    options = region_name.find("option");
    var value = options.filter(":selected").attr("value");
    tag.autocomplete({
        source: "autocomplete.php?bro=" + value,
        selectFirst: true
    });

    region_name.on("change", function() {
        value = options.filter(":selected").attr("value");
        tag.autocomplete("option", "source", "autocomplete.php?bro=" + value);
    });


});
```

Comment: sory, i have misedit my code region from my original code, because the code in my  country language, but in my original code i have $reg=mysql_fetch_array($regionQuery), i dont get error console. Any help?

Comment: Where did you put it  var valBro=$("#region_name").val(); ?

Comment: in exacly above my  autocomplet function

Comment: $("#region_name").val(); return the selected value of select. it called before the php generate value. add a timeout to get the value

Comment: sorry i am new be in php or java script, can you more detail, how i add timeout to get the value?